# Installing Solaris Studio 12.2 in Ubuntu

Tags: ide, solaris, ubuntu-10.04

I need help with installing Solaris Studio 12.2 on Ubuntu.

I looked at this question already and it didn't help: [Installing Solaris Studio 12.2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4227/installing-solaris-studio-12-2)

My problem with the solutions provided in that question is that I do not have a script to run when I extract the file I downloaded: SolarisStudio12.2-linux-x86-tar-ML.tar.bz2

To extract it I am just using the Ubuntu GUI, archive manager.
Could this be my problem?

Also I already posted this on askUbuntu: [Got no response.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33037/installing-solaris-studio-12-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no installation script to run with the tarfile distribution. You just extract the archive somewhere and that's it, Solaris Studio is installed and ready to use. You just need to add its bin directory to your PATH.

I'm not familiar with Ubuntu GUI archive manager so here is how I proceed:

```
$ bunzip2 < SolarisStudio12.2-linux-x86-tar-ML.tar.bz2 | tar xf -
$ PATH=$PWD/SolarisStudio12.2-linux-x86-tar-ML/solstudio12.2/bin cc -V           
cc: Sun C 5.11 Linux_i386 2010/08/13
usage: cc [ options ] files.  Use 'cc -flags' for details
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I got it almost working now. I am just having trouble installing Java and having SolStudio find it. I'll post another question about this.