# Memory leak in native java aplication

Tags: java, memory-leaks, java-native-interface, dbx

Hi all!

I have a Native Java application in linux and i want detect memory weak. I try used Valgrind but seem that don't work fine. Then I tried to also install `dbx (Oracle Studio)` but it seems that is not available for `Ubuntu 14.04`. Is there another solution that can be used to detect these leaks ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommendations for a heap analysis tool for Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064427/recommendations-for-a-heap-analysis-tool-for-java)

Comment: Are you trying to fix a Java heap memory link (objects not being garbage collected) or a native-code memory leak (`malloc`-ed memory not being `free`-ed)?

Comment: native-code memory leak

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541309/installing-solaris-studio-12-2-in-ubuntu for running Solaris Studio on Ubuntu

Comment: This question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041117/growing-resident-memory-usage-rss-of-java-process

Answer (score 2):

In  my opinion, the best tool you can use to detect memory leaks and performance problems is [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html)

You can easily detect both of them and it has integrations with a lot of IDEs (Eclipse, STS, Netbeans, IntelliJ, etc...).

It's not free, but you can request an evaluation key to test the tool for about 10 days.

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse MAT](https://eclipse.org/mat/) is a good tool to analyze memory for Java applications. They have good documentation for common use cases.

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064427/recommendations-for-a-heap-analysis-tool-for-java)